# No timestamp on standard error

Tags: ping, timestamp, stderr

Using fping and redirecting stout and stderr to the same file.

```
fping -lDf IPlist >IPoutput 2>&1
```

The "host unreachable" error messages in the file have no timestamps.

How do I get timestamps on those?

Answer (score 0):

`fping -lDf IPlist    2>&1   | logger`

Then check the syslog, typically your output will appear in `/var/log/messages` or `/var/log/syslog`

A side effect of syslog is that it timestamps all entries.